# Code works when inside a .tex file but not when implemented in a .cls file

Tags: document-classes

A few moments ago I was struggling with the problem of doing calculations inside a tex file. I wanted a value to be given and the the `\vspace` function to take that value as its parameter after a few math. What I wanted to do was to obtain, for a given value `x`

```
\vspace{(x-1)0.6 cm}
```

I showed my broken code and it was fixed in following way

```
\documentclass[]{paper}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\titlelines}[1]{\def\@TitleLines{#1}}
\titlelines{1}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{(\@TitleLines cm-1cm)*\real{0.6}}
\makeatother


\title{text \\ \vspace*{\mylength} more text}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

When I compile this code it works perfectly. Now, however, I would like to put it inside a .cls file I'm working on for my supervisor. Inside the .cls file I have this piece of code, which also works perfectly

```
\title{
\begin{center}
\fontsize{\@TitleSize}{\@TitleSpacing}
\usefont{T1}{\@TitleFont}{b}{n}
\color{\@TitleColor}
\selectfont
\shadowtext{\begin{tabular}{c}\@TheTitle\end{tabular}}
\vspace*{0.6cm}
\\
\end{center}
\@Abs
}

\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\def\@TheTitle{#1}}
```

Here `\@TitleStuff` are just font customisations for the title. `\@Abs` is the abstract. The `\vspace` function inside `\title{...}` is the one I'm trying to deal with. When I insert the piece of code

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\titlelines}[1]{\def\@TitleLines{#1}}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{(\@TitleLines cm-1cm)*\real{0.6}}
\makeatother
```

before the `\title{}` bit and then substitute `\vspace*{0.6cm}` for `\vspace*{\mylength}`, the .tex file compiled with this class gives me an error. It says `\@TitleLines` was not defined. Do you know what could be giving this error? I know its not practical do post the whole .cls file but if you have a guess on what is wrong I would thank you very much.

Comment: Omit `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` when copying the code to the `.cls` file and try again… ;-)

Comment: The problem is that you don't have `\titlelines{1}` or something similar in your `.cls` file which defines `\@TitleLines`. If you don't use this before (re)calculating the length, your command will be undefined and, hence, the length setting fails.

Comment: I omitted \makeletter and \makeatother and it did not work.

@Siracusa... I don't understand. Isn't the line \newcommand{\titlelines}[1]{\def\@TitleLines{#1}} already defining \@TitleLines? When I write before everything \def\@TitleLines{0.6}, for example, it works but then the function \titlelines, which goes inside the .tex file, don't have any effect.

Comment: For sure, `\makeatletter` and (especially) `\makeatother` do not belong there, and the `.cls` file cannot work if you include them.  In the second place, you must execute `\titlelines` before using the value of `\@TitleLines`.

Comment: In the .txt file I call \titlelines before \title. In the .cls file \titlelines and \@TitleLines are connected through the definition of \titlelines: \newcommand{\titlelines}[1]{\def\@TitleLines{#1}}. Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: I’m still trying to figure out exactly what your supervisor’s class is doing.  What error message do you get?

Comment: it says: undefined control sequence <argument> \@TitleLines...h}{(\@TitleLines cm-1cm)*\real{0.6}}

Comment: If before the \newcommand{\titlelines}... part in the .cls file I write \def\@TitleLines{2}, for example, everything works but nothing changes when I change the argument of \titlelines in the .txt. It becomes useless.

Comment: Exactly where in your `.tex` file do you use the `\titlelines` command?

Comment: I use \titlelines and then \title. Both before \begin{document} and before \maketitle

Comment: What is puzzling me is that other functions are defined in the same way but give no trouble. The title font size for instance. I define a default value with \@TitleSize{30} and then a function \newcommand{\titlesize}[1]{\def\@TitleSize{#1}}. When I call \titlesize in the .txt file it overrides the default value. No error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49821/discussion-between-gustavo-mezzetti-and-gabu).

Comment: This whole question seems to be working with a wrench and a hammer on a problem that needs to be fixed with a screwdriver. Something serious is going wrong with the starting code. Have you (your supervisor) read the wikibook page on title creation?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look, what the class code above does:

```
\newcommand{\titlelines}[1]{\def\@TitleLines{#1}}
```

`\titlelines` is defined. Each usage of `\titlelines` will (re)define `\@TitleLines`.

```
\newlength{\mylength}
```

New length `\mylength` is defined.

```
\setlength{\mylength}{(\@TitleLines cm-1cm)*\real{0.6}}
```

`\@TitleLines` is used to calculate and set the value of `\mylength`. But at this time, `\titlelines` have not been used, so `\@TitleLines` is still undefined. And that is also the main difference to the first code. There you have had

```
\titlelines{1}
```

before the calculation. This usage of `\titlelines` has defined `\@TitleLines`.

So, the problem with the class code above is, that `\mylength` is not (re)calculated just after defining `\@TitleLines` but just after defining `\titlelines`, before calling `\titlelines` and therefore without defined `\@TitleLines`. You can solve this by defining a default for `\@TitleLines` before the first usage *and* (re)calculating `\mylength` either just after each redefinition of `\@TitleLines` or before each usage of `\@TitleLines`. So you can either do:

```
\newcommand{\titlelines}[1]{\def\@TitleLines{#1}}
\newlength{\mylength}
\newcommand*{\@TitleLines}{1}
\newcommand*{\title}{%
  \setlength{\mylength}{(\@TitleLines cm-1cm)*\real{0.6}}%
  …
  \vspace{\mylength}%
  …
}
```

or

```
\newlength{\mylength}
\newcommand{\titlelines}[1]{%
  \def\@TitleLines{#1}%
  \setlength{\mylength}{(\@TitleLines cm-1cm)*\real{0.6}}%
}
\newcommand*{\@TitleLines}{1}
```

But I would suggest to simply eliminate the macro and replace the auxiliary length `\mylength` by length `\@TitleLines`:

```
\newlength{\@TitleLines}
\newcommand*{\titlelines}[1]{%
  \setlength{\@TitleLines}{0.6cm*(#1-1)}%
}
```

So you can again use `\vspace{\@TitleLines}` instead of `\vspace{\mylength}`. If you add `\dimexpr` to the calculation, you even don't need package `calc`:

```
\newlength{\@TitleLines}
\newcommand*{\titlelines}[1]{%
  \setlength{\@TitleLines}{\dimexpr 0.6cm*(#1-1)\relax}%
}
```

Alternatively you could still use a macro `\@TitleLines` and move the usage of `\dimexpr` to the usage of `\vspace`:

```
\newcommand*{\@TitleLines}{1}
\newcommand*{\titlelines}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@TitleLines}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\title}{%
   …
   \vspace{\dimexpr 0.6cm*(\@TitleLines-1)\relax}
   …
}
```